# Delelopment environment for jruby rails in windows with vagrant and chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, chef-infra, vagrant

Is it worth it to setup chef with vagrant to develop rails apps in windows (interrested in jruby) and then deploy it to cloud? I am trying to figure out how to setup a nice development environment for windows (windows 7 64 bit) but I am a bit lost.

Comment: So you want to spawn a Windows VM? What is your host OS?

Comment: @vishal.biyani No. My production environment will be unix based. All I want is to make the development in windows. To be more clear I have a laptop with win 64 and my base workstation is a Mac. I want to be able to work in both.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is a good tool to replicate production environments on your local machine. It lets you configure one or many VMs to simulate load balancers, web servers, and production data storage systems all on your computer.

Some people find it simpler to install Vagrant as a development environment as well. You get a shared folder that allows you to code on your host OS and then "deploy" immediately to a simulated production environment and test on your machine. However, it's not 100% necessary and some developers dislike having to fire up a VM to start coding.

I use a combination of both. I develop locally and test changes locally, and then I use Vagrant to fire up VMs and test my code in a simulated environment.

Comment: Do you use windows as dev environment?